# Mysql Database hosting for android app

Tags: java, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud

Im on a project for my college, an android app that shows the results of all semesters and attendance details for prarent and that would require a centralized web server which must have a mysql db hooked up,I have done things locally with mysql and php but this is kinda big as i am new to cloud db hosting,So for a userbase of 1200 customers which hosting service should i choose for eg.000webhosting offers free db hosting while godaddy is paid I only need the web server for a basic website and a mysql db nothing else it would be lesser than 300mb or less and  godaddy offers economic and other plans  check it out [here](https://in.godaddy.com/offers/web-hosting/linux?isc=hos1in76&countryview=1&currencytype=INR&slid=&pgrid=53128575074&ptaid=aud-302891163545:kwd-381844080157&mkwid=sexh2ulT7_pcrid_243747894227_pkw_godaddy%20linux%20web%20hosting_pmt_e_pdv_c_&gclid=CjwKCAiAz-7UBRBAEiwAVrz-9ehs7T9TEhwigrIOFgCUQrGRTtXOgi15azyFKfTLA35I7svBbs-VoBoCLGoQAvD_BwE)  Which plan should i choose and i have also seen amazon web services which one should i take for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I am using Amazon web services for past couple of months and i think it suits your requirements too.

**Pros of Using AWS:**

1. AWS gives free 1 year use of all of its main services which comes handy where you can host two servers **1 UNIX and 1 Windows** for a year for free and it has limits per month *i.e. 750 hours for each* of the server which is more than enough.
2. It includes **1 dedicated static IP** for a year which they call 'Elastic IP'.

And at last even if you will exceed limits they have very minimal charges. Hope, this helps.